# RegEx that checks if a character doesn't exist in a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to create a RegEx that checks if a character doesn't appear at any moment of a line following a pattern.

I have the following log:

```
3/9/18, 17:47 - Person 1: Hello guys!
3/10/18, 22:59 - Person 2 joined the group.
3/10/18, 09:35 - Person 2: Sup!
What's cracking?
3/10/18, 09:36 - Person 1: Not much...
```

And I'm reading one line at a time, so I need to discard lines that have the following pattern: `date, hour - warning.`, like the second line in the example above, since they are lines of the system and not of the conversation.

All I managed to do until now is this RegEx:

```regex
\d*\/\d*\/\d*, \d*:\d* - (?!\:)
```

But the negative lookeahead `(?!\:)` only checks the character after the `-`, not the rest of the string. How can I force this RegEx to check if there's no `:` in the rest of the string?

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hgq4r8/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^` matching 0+ times not a newline or `:` and then match `:` inside the negative lookahead

Note to match `\d+` to match 1+ digits and not match `//, : -`

```
\d+/\d+\/\d+, \d+:\d+ - (?![^\r\n:]*:)
```

About the last part:

- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `[^\r\n:]*` match 0+ times any char other than a newline or colon
  - `:` Match the colon
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1j9G8y/1)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I force this RegEx to check if there's no **`:`** in the rest of the
>   string?

With lookahead assertion:

```
\d+/\d+\/\d+, \d+:\d+ -(?=[^:]+$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/KD3kW4/1